# Select a specific button in table row that contains a specific text using Selenium, python and Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

I'm trying to click on a button in a row that contains a specific text by using XPath.

```py
    #webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element[0]).click(element[0]).perform()
    test  = element.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="btn btn-sm btn-link text-success"]')
    print(test)
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(test[0]).click(test[0]).perform()
```

This method doesn't work properly, it can found the row and click the button needed but if I make it in a boucle, it will always click the button in the first row, and not on the asked one.

This is a screenshot of the situation:

[image: Screenshot]

and this is the code of the table HTML :

```html
    <tbody _ngcontent-c7="" class="no-drag"><!----><tr _ngcontent-c7="" style="background-color: inherit;"><!----><td _ngcontent-c7="" class="align-middle pr-1"><!----><a _ngcontent-c7="" class="btn btn-sm btn-link text-success"><i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-play " style="cursor: pointer;" tooltip="Display" aria-describedby="tooltip-176"></i></a><!----><a _ngcontent-c7="" class="btn btn-sm btn-link"><i _ngcontent-c7="" style="cursor: pointer;" tooltip="Display" class="fa fa-play" aria-describedby="tooltip-177"></i></a><!----><a _ngcontent-c7="" class="btn btn-sm btn-link text-danger"><i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-remove " style="cursor: pointer;" tooltip="Remove" aria-describedby="tooltip-178"></i></a><!----></td><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><td _ngcontent-c7="" class="align-middle pr-1"><span _ngcontent-c7="" aria-describedby="tooltip-179"> Blue_Coat_basic Wed Apr 14 2021 21-14-36 </span></td><td _ngcontent-c7="" class="align-middle pr-1"><span _ngcontent-c7="" aria-describedby="tooltip-180"> 2021/04/14 21:15:04 </span></td><!----><!----><!----></tr></tbody>
```

Comment: consider adding the  website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `test[0]).click(test[0])`

Try this

```
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(test).click(on_element=test).perform()
```

Or use `xpath`

```
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr/td[@class='align-middle pr-1']//a[@class='class='btn btn-sm btn-link text-success']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp):

```
 your_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Blue_Coat')]")
 your_button.click()
```

Or for the case when this text is inside a, use:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Blue_Coat')]
```

Instead of `Blue_Coat` put a text you see.

If it won't work, add more detailed html, a link or paste it to your question.

Comment: I've put the HTML code table that contained the buttons and name of the filter, , plz take a look. as I mentioned, I would select the row by the name after that I would click the green button. the problem is when the table contains more than one element. I should select the suitable row by the name and after that click the button. Thanks for your help